# Python: If command and Socket

Tags: python, sockets

I am having a client read a text file and send that data to a server. I want the client to read the text file and see if what it just read is identical to what it had sent the previous iteration. When I run the function, the program sends the contents of the text file once to the server and then stops. Without trying to stop it from sending the same thing over and over again, the program works perfectly.

I have tried moving `check = move_pos` inside and outside the if statement, but it doesn't make a difference.

```
import socket, linecache

HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 5555
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))

move_pos = ['0','0','0','0','0']

check = ['0','0','0','0','0']

while True:
    for i in range(len(move_pos)):
      pos = linecache.getline('positions.txt',i+1)
      move_pos[i] = str(pos.strip("\n"))
      linecache.clearcache()

    if move_pos != check:
        n = "\n"
        posstr = n.join(move_pos)
        s.send(posstr.encode())
        data = ''
        data = s.recv(1024).decode()
        print (data)

    check = move_pos

s.close()
```

I am new to Python so I am sure this is just a stupid mistake, but I would appreciate the help.

Comment: So, remind me what is the point of `s.send(...)`, and then `s.recv(...)`?

Comment: After `check = move_pos`, you now have only a single list, with two names referring to it.  They will always compare as equal after that point, since any change made via one name is visible via the other name.

Comment: How do I go about comparing them without creating a single list? Thank you. Also s.send and s.recv are socket functions. I'm using the socket module to send data through my network to another device.